# Internet Explorer 8 displaying chart only in half of the screen

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I have an application which tries to render a bar chart . It is being displayed correctly in 
Internet Explorer 7 but not in Internet explorer 8. In IE8 it only uses half of the screen
to display chart ,in IE7 it uses the whole of it. The chart is also being displayed correctly in chrome and firefox. The application uses jsp and servlets to create this page.

Comment: What is the width of the container element?

Comment: Could you show some code or even better the reduced test case on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Codes being generated using servlets and jsp. And the html page source that i can look in either page looks to be same.

Comment: In firebug i am seeing an embed tag for applet. But there is none in IE version. So can this be how embed is handled in IE??

Comment: @HassanVoyeau : width it shows is 100%. In this we are trying to embed   an applet through a jsp page.

Answer (score 0):

the issue was occuring because of some tags that were created to prevent csrf attacks. undoing them was doing the trick